# Edit blog_style_default_item_title.php

Tags: layout

I would like to edit the file **blog_style_default_item_title.php** so that the head of the articles appeared in the publication date and the label disappeared "published:" Can you help me, what is the parameter that contains the date that interests me?

I wrote:

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_title')): ?>

<h2 itemprop="name">

<?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHED_DATE_ON', JHTML::_('dates', $this->item->publish_up, JText::_('d / m / Y'))); ?>
```

Inside the file is not present and is inserted to the current date and I still have to remove the label "published".

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not ever edit the core layouts. [Use the overrides](http://joom3.zemplate.com/other-topics/52-joomla-3-2/111-creating-template-overrides-in-joomla-3-2).

When you override `edit blog_style_default_item_title.php` try this code:

```
<time datetime="<?php echo JHtml::_('date', $displayData->publish_up, 'c'); ?>" itemprop="datePublished">
<?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $displayData->publish_up, 'd / m / Y')); ?>
</time>
```

And the "published:" is inside `/layouts/joomla/content/info_block/publish_date.php`. Override it an remove the necessary code.